# How does the sound change from L. "benedictionem" to O.Fr. "beneiçon" happen?

Tags: sound-change, romance-languages, latin, french

[***benison***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=benison&allowed_in_frame=0)

> c.1300, "blessing, beatitude," from O.Fr. **beneiçon** "blessing, benediction," from L. ***benedictionem*** (see benediction).

Similarly, the word *[**malison**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=malison&searchmode=none)* comes in the exact way described above.

In other words, is it a regular sound change? Such as a sound law?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks mostly regular.

The (classical) Latin *benedictiōnem* /benediktioːnẽ/. In Western Romance, changes that would apply:

- Intervocalic voiced obstruents like /d/ tend to get elided: /edi/ > /ei/
- Plosives in the coda get vocalized (when followed by another plosive): /ikti/ > /ijti/ > /iti/. Compare [*authority*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=authority&allowed_in_frame=0) < Old French *auctorité* < Latin *auctoritas*
- Close vowels lose their syllabicity when adjacent to other vowels: /eitioː/ > /ejtjoː/
- /tj/ gets affricated to something like /tsj/, as in *-tion*
- Latin endings like /ẽ/ often fall off or get reduced

Combining these sound changes, we get something like /benejtsjon/. (The sound /ts/ was often written *c* or *ç*.)

The same applies for /malediktioːnẽ/ > /malejts(j)on/.

I'm not sure why the /j/ after /ts/ is lost here; it might be idiosyncratic.

Comment: It is really amazing to know the process with so many steps of just one sound correspondence. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Some small errors: (1) Latin short i is lowered to /e/ in Western Romance, so we wouldn't get /edi/ > /ei/ (see below for explanation of written *ei*). (2) In the history of French, there is no sound change where close vowels lose their syllabicity. Instead, the first vowel would be lost. (3) Although /kt/ is indeed normally vocalized to /jt/, this doesn't happen in /ktj/, which instead becomes /ttsj/.

Answer (score 6):

Some corrections compared with Mechanical Snail's answer:

- "Old French" *beneiçon* (also written *beneison*) is actually Anglo-French (Norman French). Standard Old French would be more like *benoiçon* or *benoison*. Anglo-French tended to reduce *ei* to *e*, and indeed the Middle English form was *beneson*.
- The *ei* in this word is probably irregular. Compare Latin *directiāre* > Old French *drecier* > Modern French *dresser*, not **droisser*; we would thus expect **beneçon*. The ending *-eison* is the normal outcome of Latin *-itiōnem*, and probably occurs in *beneison* by analogy, with *beneiçon* a mixed form.
- So you might expect changes like *benedictiōnem* > Proto-Western-Romance (PWR) /benedetts<sup>j</sup>one/ (Latin short i becomes PWR /e/) > /beneets<sup>j</sup>one/ (*d* lost by lenition, double consonants simplified) > /benets<sup>j</sup>on/ (loss of intertonic and final *e*) > /benetson/ (simplification of palatal consonant) > expected **beneçon*, replaced by *beneison* or *beneiçon* by analogy.
- Note that the loss of /j/ after /ts/ is regular. French words in *-tion* are direct borrowings from Church Latin (that's why the pronunciation has /s/ despite the classicizing spelling).