# Is there a diagram showing the history of sound changes from Latin to the Romance languages?

Tags: historical-linguistics, reference-request, sound-change, romance-languages

We have had a number of questions about [sound changes](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-change), asking for the history of specific changes. See this one, for example: asking about the change [from Latin *benedictionem* to French *beneiçon*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2604/22). Often, as the original poster of that question observed, the process can be explained by a series of steps of just one sound correspondence. As far as I know, each sound change is only productive for a certain period of time in a language. Of course, different changes may be occurring simultaneously, so overlaps of these periods are expected.

I am looking for something more general: a diagram — probably a tree-shaped one — that shows the development from Latin into the Romance languages. The diagram must meet the following requirements:

- Shows at least two of the major six Romance languages: Spanish, Portuguese, French, Italian, Romanian and Catalan.
- Each branch shows the history of the language from Vulgar Latin to the present day.
- Each branch has the sound changes and their respective (approximate) periods annotated.
- For each language, any variety can be chosen, as long as it remains the same throughout the diagram.

Is there some book, site, whatever, where one can find such a diagram?

Comment: I have never seen anything like that - such a diagram would be ginormous.

Comment: I saw a Pascal program once that simply went through the appropriate set of changes and produced Spanish words at one end when Latin words were entered at the other. It can't be that hard to consult a book. In fact, an exam something like this (though not with much phonology) is required for university entry in Mexico. I get a new textbook for that class every time I'm in Mexico; it's very useful. Editorial Esfinge, Mex DF, _Compendio de Etymologías Grecolatinas del Español_, by Agustín Mateos Muñoz.

Comment: @AlexB. yes it would. But it doesn't need to be a single image, for example. A software application with the ability to collapse and expand nodes in graph would be ok. Something like [mind maps](http://mind42.com/mindmap/062654a2-9b7c-4411-b1c0-f7daeb9c4f88?rel=pmb).

Comment: I would include Catalan in the list of major Romance languages because it is standardized and literary. Tons of books are published in Catalan for instance and I don't think this is the case for other Romance languages like Aromanian, Friulian, Galician, Ladin, Ligurian, Occitan, Provencal, Romansh, Sardinian, etc.

Comment: @hippietrail You're right. Done.

Comment: Ever see this??    http://www.amazon.com/Peter-Boyd-Bowman/e/B001JWWQ2I/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1

Comment: @hippietrail I think many of those you mentioned (and others), there is good standardization and publication.  Galician and Asturian are standardized with a good amount of literary publication, and I'd imagine similar for Provençal and Sardinian, at least (though I don't have personal experience with them)

Comment: I was thinking about something like this recently, except using mathematical functions instead of a diagram.  I think it might be possible with some simplifications (i.e., don't account for exceptional words) and by using the fact that a lot of Romance languages have nice phoneme-to-orthography maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otavio, I am afraid, you will not be spared the expense and the honour to come up with the full chart yourself. However, the following might be helpful:

[Diachronic Studies in Romance Linguistics](https://books.google.hu/books?id=D6jU7q1Xkf0C&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a rudimentary outline for some changes.

[From Latin to Modern French: on diachronic changes and synchronic Variations](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00365006/PDF/vaissiere_1996_from_latin_to_modern_French.pdf) meets some of your other criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of a complete chart existing, but the book "From Latin to Romance in Sound Charts" by Peter Boyd-Bowman does contain many of the sound changes from Latin across the Romance languages. These changes could be unified into a large table or chart.